# MutationObserver and Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom, mutation-observers

I'm using Polymer's ShadowDOM and `MutationObserver` polyfills and need to:

- Detect when a `HTMLCanvasElement` is inserted so that I can perform layout (its width and height are undetermined through `offsetWidth` / `offsetHeight` when detached from the DOM tree)
- Detect when the element is removed so I can halt its `requestAnimationFrame` loop

Traditionally, without Shadow DOM, this works as follows:

1. Attach `MutationObserver` to `document.body` and perform `querySelectorAll` for any canvas elements
2. Perform some method, e.g. `layoutNode` on these elements
3. If in the animation loop `document.body.contains(node)` returns `false`, then the node has been removed from the DOM

When using Shadow DOM I can get around the shadow dom boundaries by performing (what seems to be very inefficient) scans across all elements in the DOM that have roots which have been added, and performing `layoutNode` on any shadow dom nodes inheriting from `HTMLCanvasElement`.

How do I check from the animation loop of the canvas that this node is still in the DOM tree?

Is there a better API to use for detecting when a DOM node has been inserted?

(NB. MutationEvents are unavailable using Polymer's CustomElements polyfill.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can use the following function attached to a Node to check whether the node is eventually rooted (through multiple shadow dom boundaries) at a given document, or the current document if no document is specified. This should be as efficient as a JS-based `root.contains(node)` call.

```
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'isAttachedToDocument', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: function(document) {
        document = document || window.document;
        var el = this;
        while(el.parentNode || el.host) el = el.parentNode || el.host;
        return (el.impl || el) === document;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could also use one of these:

[ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

> The ResizeObserver interface reports changes to the dimensions of an
> Element's content or border box, or the bounding box of an SVGElement.

When the contents of a Shadow DOM changes, the `MutationObserver` is not notified, because it doesn't see any change in it's own DOM. But the change in the Shadow DOM might have an effect on the size of the Shadow DOM containing element. This size change can be observed with the `ResizeObserver`.

This one could also be worth looking at:

[Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe
> changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor
> element or with a top-level document's viewport.